# Interface of vim to other programs

Tags: vim

I am wondering whether vim has something like an API used by other programs. For example, a command that allows other programs to set vim states or insert particular characters at particular position when using vim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vim has a socket interface which was originally implemented for netbeans and allows integration into a development environment, such as using breakpoints with a debugger (see [`:help netbeans`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/netbeans.html#netbeans)).

There's also the client-server interface which lets vim send/accept commands over a socket (see [`:help clientserver`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html#clientserver)).